# How do I get audio from the GamePad headphone jack?

Tags: wii-u

The Wii U's GamePad has a headphone jack. However, when I plug my headphones in, I don't hear any audio. **How do I get my game's audio to output to the GamePad's headphone jack?**

Comment: It depends on the game/software you're using. Are you normally hearing audio out of the GamePad's speakers?

Comment: The GamePad has speakers?! No. No audio comes from the GamePad's speakers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I feel a bit foolish. There is a slider on the top labeled "Volume". When I slide it toward the + side, my headphones and speakers started working. Amazing.

Comment: Darn, that is one of the few questions on this site that I could have answered ;)